# AuthCheckPhone Telegram Api java

Tags: java, telegram

Есть база данных на 350 тыс. номеров. Мне нужно проверить каждый номер на регистрацию в телеграмме. может кто то помочь? Нужен пример использования функции `authCheckPhone`. Я так понимаю авторизация для этого не нужна

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык